# SphinxSE Returning Strange Results

Tags: sphinx

I have the following SphinxSE query that is returning some strange results:

```
select distinct
model,
keywords,
`name`,
image,
products_parent_status,
`status`,
final_price,
source,
source_id,
description,
subdescription,
language_id,
feature,
var_val,
weight
from __search
where query='@(keywords,name,model,image,description,subdescription,feature,var_val) about;
fieldweights=keywords,11,model,10,name,9,feature,8,var_val,7,description,6,subdescription,5,image,4;
mode=extended;
maxmatches=500000;
ranker=proximity_bm25;
limit=20'
order by weight desc, `name`;
```

If I search for "about", I get the exact number of results I was anticipating but if I search for "abo" I get no results.  Does it have something to do with the ranker I am using?  I have tried other ones but I still get the same strange behavior.  Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I figured it out.  Had to add min_prefix_len setting to my index.  Added it in and started getting the exact matches that I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Closing issue.  Added asterisks around the search term and min_prefix_len to index.